# Determinant of 2 transpose matrix A and B.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Can you show me why $\det(A^T B^T) = \det(A)\det(B^T) = \det(A^T)\det(B)$ ?

im really having a hard time finding its properties. i dont know what to search.
please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only result you need here is that $\det(A)=\det(A^T)$ and that $A^T B^T = (BA)^T$.

Comment: thank you very much. i totally forgot that simple thm!